# how to make clean url using htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

for e.g. my domain is www.examples.com and subdomain is test2.examples.com
I am using url variable to link pages.
e.g.test2.examples.com/index.php?page=registers
but I want  clean url like
test2.examples.com/page/registers

How can I do this using HTACCESS file.
can I use HTACCESS for subdomain or it will not allow

Comment: What Content Management System are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for URL Rewriting, it will answer all your needs., see this [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)